# Getting Started with Python-Twitch 1.2

Tags: python, twitch

I've been programming with Python for a few months now but I'm having trouble figuring out the Python-Twitch library for the Twitch API.  I've installed version 1.2 and it gives instructions here: http://ingwinlu.github.io/python-twitch/quickstart.html#dependencies

However, I'm completely inexperienced with doing this type of thing.  Even just using their example of

```
from twitch.api import v3
```

returns a "no module named twitch" error..

Where would I get started with this? Any help would be greatly appreciated, sorry for my lack of knowledge.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you seeking installation help?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to _use_ it.  How to import, what to do with the api modules, etc. and with what syntax.  In my lack of understanding of the Python-Twitch documentation page, I tried to find someone's example code online but there was none.

Answer (score -1):

If calling `from twitch.api import v3` returns the following error:

> no module named twitch

Then you do not have the <kbd>python-twitch</kbd> module properly installed.

---

First make sure you have an up to date version of Python, such as  3.5.1 from https://www.python.org/downloads/

Then install it (if not already installed) using the recommended options including PIP

Then go to the Python\Scripts directory, such as:

> C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts>

Then run the following:

```
pip install python-twitch
```

Now you should see something like this:

> Collecting python-twitch
>       Downloading python-twitch-1.2.0.tar.gz
>   Collecting six>=1.9.0 (from python-twitch)
>       Downloading six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   Installing collected packages: six, python-twitch
>       Running setup.py install for python-twitch
>   Successfully installed python-twitch-1.2.0 six-1.10.0\

Now re-run your test python file:

```
from twitch.api import v3
```